# Lagrange multipliers with 3 constrains

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

So I have this problem with the following task.

Find the points that satisfy necessary condition for existance of minimas:

$f(x,y)=-(x^2+y^2)$ constrains $\begin{cases} x + 2y\leq3\\ x\geq0 \\ y\geq0 \end{cases}$

The problem is that after creating system of equations for gradients I compare them to 0 and end up with one more unknown variable.

Comment: System of 5 equations with 5 unknowns should work well. Could you show your work?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ECUF.jpg

Comment: Now i have 2 equations with 3 multipliers

Comment: Now I see what is wrong: the last three equations must be Complementary Slackness Principle instead, not derivatives. Like $\lambda_1(x+2y-3)=0$, $\lambda_2 x=0$, $\lambda_3 y=0$.

Comment: Ohh, now I see.. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Introducing three slack variables $\{s_k\}$ we transform the inequalities into equations and the Lagrangian formulation gives

$$
L(x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,s_1,s_2,s_3) = x^2+y^2+\lambda_1(x+2y-3+s_1^2)+\lambda_2(x-s_2^2)+\lambda_3(y-s_3^2)
$$

so the stationary points are given by the solutions to

$$
\nabla L = 0 = \cases{ \lambda_1+\lambda_2+2 x \\
 2 \lambda_1+\lambda_3+2 y \\
 s_1^2+x+2 y-3 \\
 x-s_2^2 \\
 y-s_3^2 \\
 \lambda_1 s_1 \\
 \lambda_2 s_2 \\
 \lambda_3 s_3 \\}
$$

with $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ the feasible results are

| $f$ | $x$ | $y$ | $s_1^2$ | $s_2^2$ | $s_3^2$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $0$ | $3$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $\dfrac{9}{5}$ | $\dfrac{3}{5}$ | $\dfrac{6}{5}$ | $0$ | $\dfrac{3}{5}$ | $\dfrac{6}{5}$ |
| $\dfrac{9}{4}$ | $0$ | $\dfrac{3}{2}$ | $0$ | $0$ | $\dfrac{3}{2}$ |
| $9$ | $3$ | $0$ | $0$ | $3$ | $0$ |

Here $s_k = 0$ indicates that the corresponding restriction is actuating.

Comment: Nice! Could you explain what the last matrix was? Is it the matrix of second-order mixed partial derivatives? But I don't get why the first entry is $f$? (Sorry, I'm also almost a beginner on this topic.)

Comment: The last matrix is a table of results after the stationary equations solution. To solve those equations is quite easy. Note that from $\lambda_ks_k=0$ we can simplify a lot. Here $f=x^2+y^2$

Comment: So you meant a table rather than a matrix, didn't you? You can reject my edit if I was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Could you give any reference so that I could learn more about this method (about turning inequalities into equalities for LM)? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: In the net you can find some references like this one http://users.wpi.edu/~pwdavis/Courses/MA1024B10/1024_Lagrange_multipliers.pdf